# IOS: VoiceOver changes to English in WebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, voiceover

I'm adding VoiceOver support to an app which at the moment only supports Norwegian. For most of the app VoiceOver correctly reads the text as Norwegian.

However, one page contains a webview which shows the terms and conditions (downloaded from a URL). For this page VoiceOver switches to English voice, even though this text is still in Norwegian.

I've tried to set accessibilityLanguage to "nb-NO" for both the webview and the containing viewcontroller but the text is still read as English. Do anyone know how I can make the webview be read in Norwegian?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider adopting the [lang](https://www.w3schools.com/TagS/att_global_lang.asp) HTML attribute. This will trigger VoiceOver to generate speech in the appropriate language. Hat tip to [Adrian Roselli](http://adrianroselli.com/2015/01/on-use-of-lang-attribute.html) for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Trying adding HTML lang="" attribute in your page. you can refer below url http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry for more specific value for lang attribute.
Hope this will help